# Behavior for #datepicker onselect not working

Tags: datetime, javascript

i have a datepicker in a webform. I want to be notified when a date is selected in the datepicker. In my form template i drupal_add_js a js starting with :

```
Drupal.behaviors.booking_form_tma = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        for (var id in Drupal.settings.date_popup) {
            alert('found');
            var datepicker_settings = Drupal.settings.date_popup[id].settings;
            datepicker_settings.onSelect = function(dataText) {
                alert('selected: ' + dataText);
            };
            $('#' + id).datepicker(datepicker_settings);
        }
    }
};
```

The behavior attach code gets called only once, after the page gets loaded and never reach the alert: i guess the datepicker is not present in the div at this time. When the datepicker icon is clicked, the datepicker gets injected in a div but the behavior is not called and so nothing happen. None of the alert in the code above are shown.

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/images/calander.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate:'0',
        onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
                //alert("here");
            } 
    });
 });
```

you can also write above code in js file

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers

Comment: Plus, this is not the code you should use for Drupal, since it doesn't even use behaviors. The question is another one, though, and this post doesn't answer it.

Comment: This is not good code as it does not use the Drupal JavaScript API at all, and does not even answer the question, since it doesn't address the problem with Drupal behaviors.